# Adding an id to php

Tags: php, css

Right now I have this.

```
<div>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_button id="zzz" radius="square" style="flat" url="/#subscribe"    size="5" background="#FF9900" color="#FFFFFF" center="no"] Subscribe [/su_button]'); ?>
</div>
```

Why doesn't it work like this in css?

```
#zzz{
    position:absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Shortcodes are not HTML elements. you can't add ID if it is not supported by the shortcode developer.

Comment: do you mean wordpress's `do_shortcode`

Comment: @dreamlab he probably does.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes are not HTML elements, and therefore not all HTML attributes will work when using shortcodes. Wrap your button in a div and give it an ID:

```
<div id="zzz">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[su_button radius="square" style="flat" url="/#subscribe"    size="5" background="#FF9900" color="#FFFFFF" center="no"] Subscribe [/su_button]'); ?>
</div>
```

Shortcodes is not a PHP feature, it is a WordPress function.